# Download Excel File containing Multiple Sheets

Tags: php, excel

I want to download an excel file which contains three sheets using PHP. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I inderstand correctly, you need to **generate an Excel file from PHP** ?

If so, take a look at a PEAR component called [`Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

In the [introduction of the manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php), there is an example that looks kinda what you are trying to achieve :

```
<?php
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

// Creating a workbook
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

// sending HTTP headers
$workbook->send('test.xls');

// Creating a worksheet
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My first worksheet');

// The actual data
$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Name');
$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Age');
$worksheet->write(1, 0, 'John Smith');
$worksheet->write(1, 1, 30);
$worksheet->write(2, 0, 'Johann Schmidt');
$worksheet->write(2, 1, 31);
$worksheet->write(3, 0, 'Juan Herrera');
$worksheet->write(3, 1, 32);

// Let's send the file
$workbook->close();
?>
```

It might help you do what you want **:-)**

---

If I didn't understand and you only need to read an excel file... Well :

- to download it, you can use curl, or fopen and the like
- to read it, [`PHP-ExcelReader`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/